# Merge two rows as new row and sum according value

Tags: oracle, oracle11g

Using below query i am getting results in below format.

```
select count(o.orderid) as ORDER,u.usergroup as user 
from order_details o,user_deatils u
where o.ORDERCREATOR=u.USERNAME
and u.usergroup IN ('A','B','C','D')
group by u.usergroup;
```

ORDER   USER
10       A
20       B
30       C
40       D

but i am trying to merge C and D having different values and sum their values accordingly

```
ORDER   USER
10       A
20       B
70      C+D
```

i tried with pivot, concat but unable to get the result in desired format.

any lead would be appreciable :)

Answer (score 0):

You may aggregate using a `CASE` expression:

```
select
    case when u.usergroup = 'A' then 'A'
         when u.usergroup = 'B' then 'B'
         else 'C+D' end as user,
    count(o.orderid) as "ORDER"
from order_details o
inner join user_deatils u
    on o.ORDERCREATOR = u.USERNAME
where
    u.usergroup IN ('A','B','C','D')
group by
    case when u.usergroup = 'A' then 'A'
         when u.usergroup = 'B' then 'B'
         else 'C+D' end;
```

Answer (score 0):

Use [decode](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions040.htm) function:

```
select count(o.orderid) as ORDER,decode(u.usergroup,'C','C+D','D','C+D',u.usergroup) as user 
from order_details o,user_deatils u
where o.ORDERCREATOR=u.USERNAME
and u.usergroup IN ('A','B','C','D')
group by decode(u.usergroup,'C','C+D','D','C+D',u.usergroup);
```

Comment: thanks a lot it worked.
another small query if i want to add an alias e.g. A as North , B as South should i mention it under decode.

Comment: @S.Das yes, both in select and group by `decode(u.usergroup,'A','North','B','South',...`

Answer (score 0):

With CASE and a proper join:

```
select 
  count(o.orderid) as ORDER,
  case 
    when u.usergroup in ('C', 'D') then 'C+D'
    else u.usergroup
  end usergroup
from order_details o inner join user_deatils u
on o.ORDERCREATOR = u.USERNAME
and u.usergroup IN ('A','B','C','D')
group by usergroup;
```